# Check number of stored procedures from a different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to fix a stored procedure that we have created to count number of running procedures with a certain name.

What I am trying to do is get the number of running stored procedures that match a specific title and it works fine when the Stored Procedure executing the query is in the same Database as the procedures I am trying to count as running. But I don't understand how I can count the number of running procedures matching a name running in a different Database. I assume the dbid parameter has to be used in some way, but I don't understand how.

The database I want to count in is called "ScheduledJobs" rather than MySampleDB where I have to put the stored procedure (I can't move it to the other DB for different reasons).

Any suggestions are welcome. Here is my code:

```
USE [MySampleDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_CheckRuns2]
  @RowsAffected INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT
  object_name(st.objectid) as ProcName
FROM
  sys.dm_exec_connections as qs 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.most_recent_sql_handle) st 
WHERE
  object_name(st.objectid) is not null and OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid) like '%sp_UPDATER'
END

select @RowsAffected = @@rowcount

RETURN @RowsAffected
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass in `dbid` as an extra parameter

```sql
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) like '%sp_UPDATER'
```

> Side note: You should remove `RETURN @RowsAffected`. It is not necessary, as you are anyway passing back an `OUTPUT` parameter. Note also that most client APIs will give the rowcount in any case.